# Convert Database to CSV and Save file to folder on server

Tags: php, csv, export, save

I've have been successful in exporting my database to csv as a downloadable file. However what I now need to do is instead of creating a straight .csv file that's downloaded I need it to just save to a folder called "csv" on the server. Here is my code for the current export. I need help in the saving to the server part. CHMOD on the folder (csv) is 777

```
    $today = date('Y-m-d'); 

    $select = "SELECT * FROM goldpacks WHERE date = '$today'";

    $export = mysql_query ( $select ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

    $fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
    }

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach( $row as $value )
        {                                            
            if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
           {
                $value = "\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
    }
    $data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

    if ( $data == "" )
    {
        $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n";                        
    }

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=import.csv");
    print "$header\n$data";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to add is a call to `file_put_contents()`.  You already have your csv correctly formatted in `$data` so the write process is simple:

```
// $filename is whatever you need the file to be called
file_put_contents("/path/to/csv/" . $filename, "$header\n$data");
```

Rather than `777` permissions on the csv folder, it should be owned by user the web server runs as with `700`, or group-owned by the web server user as `770`.