# Modify php file to send content in a csv file on a ftp location

Tags: php, csv, ftp, send, auto-update

The last step of our checkout is to send a mail with the order to the admin and customer. Now i want to complete the existing code by a additional fonction. The order (specific data from the order) should be sent via csv file on a ftp location on the same server. Is this possible?

Here the e-mail part of the last step:

```
// If order status is not 0 then send update text email
if ($order_info['order_status_id'] && $order_status_id && $notify) {
    $language = new Language($order_info['language_code']);
    $language->load($order_info['language_code']);
    $language->load('mail/order');

    $subject = sprintf($language->get('text_update_subject'), html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), $order_id);

    $message  = $language->get('text_update_order') . ' ' . $order_id . "\n";
    $message .= $language->get('text_update_date_added') . ' ' . date($language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($order_info['date_added'])) . "\n\n";

    $order_status_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status WHERE order_status_id = '" . (int)$order_status_id . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$order_info['language_id'] . "'");

    if ($order_status_query->num_rows) {
        $message .= $language->get('text_update_order_status') . "\n\n";
        $message .= $order_status_query->row['name'] . "\n\n";
    }

    if ($order_info['customer_id']) {
        $message .= $language->get('text_update_link') . "\n";
        $message .= $order_info['store_url'] . 'index.php?route=account/order/info&order_id=' . $order_id . "\n\n";
    }

    if ($comment) {
        $message .= $language->get('text_update_comment') . "\n\n";
        $message .= strip_tags($comment) . "\n\n";
    }

    $message .= $language->get('text_update_footer');

    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

    $mail->setTo($order_info['email']);
    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setText($message);
    $mail->send();
}
```

I've found already some general manuals but they're to specific and not for my case. Any idea?

Comment: you will almost never find a manual with your specific case, you have to adapt the guide following your needs. if the file needs to be sent on the same server, you don't need to use FTP, you can just move it. to create a CSV file, you can use this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: do you want to store the order data into a CSV file on the same server ?

Comment: thanks C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅. I'll try it-

Comment: @Sunil Verma: Yes, but not everything. The csv file should be in another folder for a specific supplier, who needs to prepare the parts. I'll adapt the sql query to identify the specific parts.

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000627/convert-database-to-csv-and-save-file-to-folder-on-server

Comment: The last suggestion could work but how do i need to adapt my code? The tricky thing for me is the identification of the final string of the original code,  who puts the order in this csv.